# Is revision really random

Tags: .net, msbuild, versioning

For assembleinfo when you set the revision to asterisk the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.aspx) says the revision is random.  This is a problem because I don't want a lower revision number on a build that was build twice in one day.

Is it really time based or random?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are at the mercy of this default behavior. But I would suggest that you make your version numbers based off your SCM revision number. There are many articles on the net about how to do this. It has a lot of advantages, the most obvious being able to checkout the exact revision of code that corresponds to a given binary.